# Right alignment of TD HTML tag

Tags: html, sql-server, for-xml-path

For some reasons I am generating HTML code for customers of specific time period and in that code I need Dollar fields's ( 'payed' and 'charges' columns ) text right aligned, how is this possible using XML raw('tr').

```
create table #Customer
(
id varchar(500),
CustomerName varchar(500),
customertype varchar(500),
LastOrderNo varchar(500),
charges varchar(500),
Payed varchar(500)
)

insert into #Customer
select '201','Cus1','XX','on-09799','60.09$','30.00$'
union all 
select '202','Cus2','XX','on-09777','90.09$','50.00$' 
union all 
select '203','Cus3','YY','on-09766','100.09$','100.00$' 
union all 
select '204','Cus4','ZZ','on-09788','2000.09$','2000.00$' 


Declare @Body varchar(max)
set @Body=''

select @Body =@Body+'<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 >' +
                  '<tr><td width="100px" > ID</td>' +
                      '<td width="140px" >CustomerName</td>' +
                      '<td width="100px" >Customertype</td>' +
                      '<td width="100px" > LastOrderNo</td>' +
                      '<td width="100px" align="right" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b> charges</b></td>' +
                      '<td width="110px" align="right" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b> Payed</b></td></tr>'

select @Body = @Body+(SELECT  
                        td= id,'',
                        td= CustomerName,'',
                        td= customertype,'',
                        td= LastOrderNo,'',
                        td= charges,'',     
                        td= Payed,''    
                        from #Customer                          
                        For XML raw('tr'), Elements
                )+'</table>'


select @Body

select * from #Customer


drop table #Customer
```

Comment: I must be missing something here: You are describing an sql program that generates html? seems that has nothing to do with the question...more relevant would probably be the generated html and css, where we might be able to help you with your question. Also generating html directly inside an sql server procedure doesn't strike me as a good practice

Comment: Add `'text-align:right' as 'td/@style', ` right before `td= charges,'',`.  If this is added right after the SELECT it will align all the cols.  Try that.

Comment: @@alonisser HTML generation is bad practice using SQL program in routines, but sometimes for only one time we need to generate reports of specific customers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you try to change the two lines to:

```
             '<td width="100px" style="text-align:right" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b> charges</b></td>' +
             '<td width="110px" style="text-align:right" bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b> Payed</b></td></tr>'
```

You can further move the background color inside of the style with:

```
 style="text-align:right;background-color:#E6E6FA"
```

Then you can add `'text-align:right' as 'td/@style'`, right before `td= charges,'',`. If this is added right after the SELECT it will align all the cols. Try that.

```
 select @Body = @Body+(SELECT   
      td= id,'',
      td= CustomerName,'',
      td= customertype,'',
      td= LastOrderNo,'',
      [td/@align]='right',
      td= charges,'',  
      [td/@align]='right',   
      td= Payed,''    
    from #Customer                          
    For XML path('tr') ---- instead of for xml raw(tr), element
 )+'</table>'
```

Comment: @@CaptainBli this is not working, I need both column's text right aligned

Comment: Note changes to fix your problem.

Comment: yes you are right [td/@align]='right' is required right before the charges and payed column TDs, I updated your answer

Answer (score -1):

Your requirement is really weird to say the least. But since this question is about styling HTML, leave the SQL alone. Add a CSS style to your HTML file:

```
<style type="text/css">
        tr td:nth-child(5), tr td:nth-child(6) {
            text-align:right;
        }
</style>
```

This right-aligns your 5th and 6th columns, which are Charges and Payed.